# Jenkins declarative pipeline 'when' condition ignoring env var value

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I want a specific stage to run if a variable in the pipeline is null i.e. A gcloud command runs in one stage, if the output of this command is nothing, then the next stage should run. If it has a value, don't run the next stage.

Here's the stage which runs a gcloud command to populate the `ATTESTATION` variable with a value if an image has been attested by binary authorisation before.

N.B. There are some global variables such as the `ATTESTOR_NAME`, `GIT_COMMIT` and `DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME` which are defined earlier but not showing here for simplicity - the commands do work when I execute in a terminal so there is nothing wrong with the commands themselves.

```
        stage ('Check Attestation') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.IMAGE_DIGEST = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "gcloud container images describe \
                    ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}:qa-${GIT_COMMIT} --format='value(image_summary.digest)' \
                    --project ${PROJECT_ID_DEV}").trim()
                    env.ATTESTATION = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "gcloud container binauthz attestations list \
                    --attestor=${ATTESTOR_NAME} --attestor-project=${PROJECT_ID_DEV} \
                    --artifact-url=${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}@${IMAGE_DIGEST} --format='value(resourceUri)'").trim()
                }
            }
        }
```

Then in my declarative pipeline,  I only want the next binary authorisation stage to run if the `ATTESTATION` environment variable is `NULL` (because the image hasn't been attested yet).

N.B. As this is in test the branch name has to match to those defined too - again the `when {{ allOf }}` for the branch condition works fine elsewhere in the pipeline.

```
stage('Run Binary Authorisation for QA') {
            when { 
                allOf { 
                    branch QA_DEPLOY_BRANCH; branch 'qa' 
                    expression { env.ATTESTATION == null }
                    } 
                }
            steps {
                    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: '*REDACTED*', variable: 'GC_KEY')]) {
                    sh("gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${GC_KEY}")
                    script {
                        // Env vars for Binary Auth
                        KEYRING = '*REDACTED*'
                        KMS_KEY = '*REDACTED*'
                        LOCATION = '*REDACTED*'
                        PROJECT_ID = '*REDACTED*'
                        binaryAuth(GIT_COMMIT, ATTESTOR_NAME, DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_DEV, PROJECT_ID, KEYRING, KMS_KEY, LOCATION)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

`binaryAuth()` is an external custom library which again, works absolutely fine when I don't specify a conditional 'when' stage based on the ATTESTATION variable.

The issue I have is, Jenkins appears to completely ignore whether the `ATTESTATION` env var has a value or not. Expected behaviour as I stated earlier is to run the stage if the value is null, however this isn't happening. It is skipping the stage completely when it should run.

I also know that the ATTESTATION value is null because I have added this line to the pipline before to verify before:

`echo "The value of the ATTESTATION env var is: ${env.ATTESTATION}"`

...and the outcome is blank for the images that haven't been attested, and for the ones with an attestation it gives a value!

It is seeing that the `ATTESTATION` env var is null and still not executing the commands in the binaryAuth external library.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I am not mistaken comparing it to `null` checks if variable exists at all. And in your case it is set to empty string. Did you try to compare to empty string like: `expression { env.ATTESTATION == '' }`?

Comment: I haven't tried that, I will give that a go now thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ymochurad for this answer in the comments. Simply changing the comparison from `null` to `''` worked!!

> If I am not mistaken comparing it to null checks if variable exists at all. And in your case it is set to empty string. Did you try to compare to empty string like: expression `{ env.ATTESTATION == '' }`

Comment: Actually the groovy way is to relay on the [Groovy Truth](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth) and just use: `expression { env.ATTESTATION }`